# Clear vs tinted glass bakeware

Tags: baking, glass

There has been at least one question regarding baking differences between light and dark metal baking pans, and metal vs glass. Is the difference between clear and tinted glass bakeware the same as light vs dark metal?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between light and dark metals (and shiny and matte) has to do with emissivity (their ability to radiate their heat back out). Darker metals are more emissive, so stuff you bake in them or on them will brown more quickly. Glass has a low degree of conductivity, so it will heat up much more slowly than metal, but once it is hot it will retain its heat very well. Glass also has a very high emissivity (about the same as a dark, matte pan and much higher than a shiny silver pan).

To answer your question about tinted glass, the tinting will have little or no effect on conductivity. It may raise the emissivity a bit, but a relatively small amount. And keep in mind that glass already has a very high emissivity.

To quantify this, glass may have an emissivity in the range of 0.84-0.92 (1 being a perfect "black body" radiator). Tinted glass may be more like 0.85-0.95. For metal pans, it has to do with both color and matte. If the pan is dark, matte metal, it might be around 0.90, but if it's shiny it's probably more around 0.50. A shiny aluminum pan is much lower, probably around 0.10.